# Filter and create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an object as shown below:

```
var obj = [
            {id: 1, name: 'AD', key: 10}, 
            {id: 2, name: 'AD', key: 20},
            {id: 3, name: 'BD', key: 30},
            {id: 4, name: 'CD', key: 40}
         ];
```

I want to filter and create a new array which satisfies any condition. For eg: filter which have name as 'AD' and create a new array of key as:

```
[10, 20]
```

Tried .map

```
obj.map(ele => {
  return ele.name === 'AD' ? ele.key : null;
}); //it adds even nulls in the result array as [10, 20, null, null]
```

Tried .filter:

```
obj.filter(ele => {
   return ele.name === 'AD' ? ele.key : null;
});

Result: [{id: 1, name: "AD", key: 10}, {id: 2, name: "AD", key: 20}] //gives array of objects, not what I'm expecting.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a combination of those. `map` after `filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter the array and then map to get the value:

```
obj.filter(e => e.name === 'AD').map(e => e.key)
```

Another option is flatmap (check browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap))

```
obj.flatMap(e => e.name === 'AD' ? [e.key] : [])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `obj` is an array in your code.
Now the solution is simple you filter first and then map like this:

```
obj.filter(item => item.name === 'AD').map(item => item.key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()`:

```js
var obj = [{id: 1, name: 'AD', key: 10},{id: 2, name: 'AD', key: 20},{id: 3, name: 'BD', key: 30},{id: 4, name: 'CD', key: 40}];

var result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.name == "AD") acc.push(cur.key)
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [
            {id: 1, name: 'AD', key: 10}, 
            {id: 2, name: 'AD', key: 20},
            {id: 3, name: 'BD', key: 30},
            {id: 4, name: 'CD', key: 40}
         ];


function specialFilter(filt) {
  return obj.filter(el => el.name === filt).map(el => el.key)
}

console.log(specialFilter("AD"))
```